# How to edit/extend/remove pager in the admin back-end?

Tags: 7, paging

For example I just applied Mollom for antispam and everything, because the site got like 500 spam comments and 500 spam users. Now I can delete them only by selecting 50 users per page in the admin/people list and that is taking up really lots of time. I will have to remove comments and forum threads like that too page by page, 50 at the time? Would be nice to somehow extend those admin back-end pagers for various lists, like amdin/people or admin/content so I could select them all at once, or select at least 100 per each or something like that.

Maybe there's a module or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also take a look at http://drupal.org/project/admin_views which gives you a drop-in replacement for the user management page with views bulk operations integrated, which because it is implemented as a view can be made to work however you like.

Answer (score 1):

[Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) was written to handle such situations:

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.

You can build a View to filter users by whatever criteria makes sense, and use VBO to delete them all (not just those on the current page) in one go.

Answer (score 1):

When you are cancelling accounts, you are given the option to either block or delete them. You are also given the option to delete all content associated with that account. There is no reason to use separate operations for user and content. Do it all at once as you delete the accounts.